# Is it true that $\mathbb R×\mathbb N$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb N×\mathbb R$ in the lexicographic topology?

Tags: general-topology

> Is it true that $\mathbb R×\mathbb N$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb N×\mathbb R$ in the lexicographic topology?

We are trying to prove this but we are stuck. We know that the first one is linear continuum where the second one is not. But we also know that they are homeomorphic in the product topology (We proved that earlier) with $f:(a,n)\to(n,a)$. But we couldn't find a relationship between them in lexicographic topology. Can you give us some hints? Thank you for advance!

Answer (score 3):

In $\Bbb N\times\Bbb R$, then open interval of all points  lexically strictly between $(41,\pi)$ and $(43,\pi)$ consists only of one point, $(42,\pi)$. Is there any singleton set in $\Bbb R\times \Bbb N$ that is open?

Comment: I dont understand why did we use 41 and pi

Comment: @70pr4k $42$ is the ultimate answer, and $\pi$ needs no introduction